# Using sessions to confirm login

Tags: php, forms, session

I am creating a page that with a select form that, depending on the option selected, will display different information.

Before a user can get to this page they must login. I continue to check if they are logged in using a session otherwise I redirect the user to the login. If $_SESSION["admin_username"] exists then they are logged in else they are not logged in.

The issue is trying to set the session when users go between selection option. So I set the session as an action in the form tag. I thought this would only set the Session if the select form was used but it resets it wether the select form was used or not. This destroys the checking for login.

Is there a way to get around this? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
<?php require_once("../Include/connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../Include/functions.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../Include/sessions.php"); ?>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<style type="text/css">
    div {position: relative; left: 300px}
    </style>


    <head>
  <title>databaseConn</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <h2>Welcome, <?php echo (find_user_by_id($_GET["user"])["username"]); ?>!</h2>
    <?php   
            if ($_SESSION["admin_username"]) {
                echo "Logged in";
} else {
redirect_to(login.php); }

     <?php

     if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
         switch ($_POST["future"]) {
             case "At Graduation":
                echo "At Graduation";
                break;
             case "2 Years After Graduation":
                 echo "2 Years After Graduation";
                 break;
             case "5 Years After Graduation":
                 echo "5 Years After Graduation";
                break;
             case "10 Years After Graduation":
                 echo "10 Years After Graduation";
                 break;
             case "20 Years After Graduation":
                echo "20 Years After Graduation";
                break;
             case "50 Years After Graduation":
                 echo "50 Years After Graduation";
                break;
         }
     }



     echo admin_username();


     ?>
     <a href="edit_account.php?username=<?php $current_user_id; ?>">edit page</a>

          <form action="<?php $_SESSION["admin_username"] = (find_user_by_id($current_user_id)["username"]); ?>" action="main.php?user=<?php echo $current_user_id; ?>" method="post"> 
              <select name="future">
                  <option value="At Graduation">At Graduation</option>
                  <option value="2 Years After Graduation">2 Years After Graduation 2</option>
                  <option value="5 Years After Graduation">5 Years After Graduation 2</option>
                  <option value="10 Years After Graduation">10 Years After Graduation 2</option>
                  <option value="20 Years After Graduation">20 Years After Graduation 2</option>
                  <option value="50 Years After Graduation">50 Years After Graduation 2</option>
              </select>
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
          </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the admin_username function I use.

```
function admin_username() {
    if (isset($_SESSION["admin_username"])) {
        $username = $_SESSION["admin_username"];
        $_SESSION["admin_username"] = null;
        return $username;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="<?php $_SESSION["admin_username"] = (find_user_by_id($current_user_id)["username"]); ?>" action="main.php?user=<?php echo $current_user_id; ?>" method="post">
```

On this line you are setting `$_SESSION['admin_username']` to whatever `find_user_by_id($current_user_id)["username"]` returns. This might be the mistake in your code.

Also you are using the action-attribute two time.

I don't see any usage of the `admin_username()` function in your code. When is it called and what is it supposed to do?

Comment: I used it two times to both set the session and refresh the page. It seem to take both actions. Is it not supposed to?

Comment: By executing $_SESSION["admin_username"] = null; the function is basically unsetting your session

Comment: The admin_username clears the session so that the only way a user could get to the page would be to login. The session is started at the login page.

Comment: The problem is, your functions are doing too much. They only should do exactly one thing but as you see in this example, admin_username() returns the username AND sets the value in the session to null. It should only return the name

Comment: No, it would be enough if you would just check if the session is set and redirect to the login if not. There is no need to unset the session, except when using a logout. If you only set the session at the login it is enough to just check it at the beginning of every refresh